# Getting a connection string for EF Core DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write a dbcontext for EF Core and I need to get a connection string from my IConfiguration. If I ask for an IConfiguration in my constructor for this class, it should get it through dependency injection if I use this?

```cs
services.AddDbContext<PostgresContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingContext")));
```

The above code is from the Npgsql EFCore instructions but I have no idea where Configuration is coming from. I could really use some help here. Should I just use the AddSingleton method here and let DI do its thing?

Here's my class if you're interested

```cs
namespace Foo
{
    public class PostgresContext : DbContext
    {
        private PostgresSettings settings { get; init; }

        PostgresContext(IConfiguration configuration) 
        {
             settings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(PostgresSettings)).Get<PostgresSettings>();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(settings.getConnectionString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the instructions would recommend this. It tightly couples your context's settings to a specific location in the configuration data. It would be better to inject `IOptions<PostgresSettings>`, which can come from anywhere in configuration, be `new`'d up directly, or come from anywhere you might need to think of in the future.

Comment: Could you refer me to some more documentation on this? If I understand correctly, if I ask for an IOptions in my constructor My configuration should automatically find the type I request from any of my configuration sources?

Comment: As long as you do `services.Configure<PostgresSettings>(configuration.GetSection(...));`

Comment: [Options pattern in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (subclass) of DbContext should not be named PostgresContext or contain any postgres specific code.

Your dbContext should named something like

"MyAppDbContext".

This will contain DbSet(s) of your Orm-entities and their mappings.

Again, it should not contain postgres specific stuff.

...

Now, somewhere you need to say "the concrete I want to use for my EF setup is postgres".

That should be ONE place.  Your IoC registration(s).  DotNet-Core's "IoC container" is referred to as the IServiceCollection.

My postgres IoC registration looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Npgsql;

string completeConnectionString = /* get this from your IConfiguration */;

                    
services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(
                        optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(
                                completeConnectionString,
                                options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                                    maxRetryCount: 3,
                                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
                                    errorCodesToAdd: null))
                            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking),
                        ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

(Sidenote, you should not use the TrackingBehavior and ServiceLifetime items blindly. My usages are for a Asp.Net-Core application.  If you have a "winforms" type of application (client-install..you may have different settings.)

While you are currently using postgres, you should be able to TRIVIALLY change to Ms-Sql-Server by only changing the AddDbContext line.  That is a "tell-tale" sign that you actually did things "well".

Your "names" of your objects should not be tied to a specific RDBMS.

EntityFramework-Core (or any ORM for that matter) is an abstraction away from a specific RDBMS.

....

Here is a suggestion to keep your code "clean".

You might/should-probably have a .csproj that is about the Entity-Framework-Orm concerns.

And it should reference
(the versions might be 3.1'ish OR 6.0'ish OR 7.0'ish)

But pay attention to the packages.

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.10" />
```

Note, the lack of any reference that is "postgres" specific.

..

then in your "top-entry-point" layer (your asp.net-core app or dot-net-core console-app as examples)... you have a reference to:

You will have the postgres package (or ms-sql-server or whatever rdbms-to-entity-framework-core package) that you are currently targeting.

```
  <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.7" />
```

This last package reference is what allows you to do the AddDbContext using the "UseNpgsql" "choice".

.....

In a nutshell, you are not writing EF-Core code for postgres specifically.
(EF-Core is NOT ADO.NET, where in ADO.NET you probably wrote code that was rdbms specific...unless you used only the most basic SQL statements).

You are writing EF-Core code (again , an abstraction away from a specific RDBMS).......... and with (only) the AddDbContext/UseNpgsql are you choosing a concrete(rdms-provider) to use.

...

Here is a link as example.

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnetcore-hostedservice-containerized-one/blob/master/src/DataLayer.EntityFramework/Contexts/WorkerServiceExampleOneDbContext.cs#L29L39

That shows the kind of things that go in a DbContext.  and it should not be anything postgres (or any rdbms) specific.

You can also "internet search" the 2 below items:

```
AddDbContext UseNpgsql
```

and you'll find articles like:

https://code-maze.com/configure-postgresql-ef-core/

You will note their "ApplicationContext" has DbSet(s) in it... and nothing postgres specific.